# backbone-forms remove built-in validators in runtime

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-forms

I have successfully implemented backbone-forms plug-in with it's validators, for example:

```
var SampleModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        field1: {
            title: $t.field1, validators: ['required', 'number']
        },
        field2: {
            title: $t.field2, type: 'Select', options: $options.field2, validators: ['required']
        },
        notes: {
            title: $t.notes
        }
    }
});
```

Now I am trying to find "right" (at this moment - any) way to disable built-in validators, on, for example, some check box click. After checkbox is clicked, allow form to be saved without validation.

I tried to rebuild `this.model.schema` for each field without `validators` and after did `this.model.form.commit()`, but it did nothing.

Can you, please, give some advice?

EDIT:

At now, I am using "dirty" method adding additional argument into `commit` method. See Backbone-forms commit method source:

```
commit: function(options, dontValidate) {
    //Validate
    options = options || {};

    var validateOptions = {
        skipModelValidate: !options.validate
    };

    // DIRTY 
    if(!dontValidate) {
        var errors = this.validate(validateOptions);
        if (errors) return errors;
    }

    //Commit
    var modelError;

    var setOptions = _.extend({
        error: function(model, e) {
            modelError = e;
        }
    }, options);

    this.model.set(this.getValue(), setOptions);

    if (modelError) return modelError;
},
```

Comment: I don't know backbone-forms, but are you allowed to submit custom functions or just the premade ones? In our internal validation, we use functions that can query form state for more complex "toggling"

Comment: Yes, there can be made custom validators, but I think, that it would be overkill, to overwrite all validation. So I thought there should be way to toggle existing validation.